# LTSP boots to command line only

Tags: command-line, gui, ltsp

I can boot to the command line on my thin client but no GUI at all. I have followed all the steps on the guides to install LTSP but still can only get here. Can anyone please help me get the GUI working. Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.